# Strange interference on tty2-6

Tags: arch-linux, terminal

There seems to be a bunch of garbage/line characters on terminals tty2-6 (photo below). This is not consistent. Occasionally, random terminals work normally. The only things I downloaded before noticing the issue were urxvt, sakura and xterm. I'm using GNome3. Due to a bug in Gnome Terminal I decided to try other emulators. All three have since been uninstalled with pacman -Rs, so they may not be related.
[image: The problem]

Comment: Video card, driver and kernel version?

Comment: Intel Graphics, linux 4.2.2-1,

Comment: Does it happen when you boot with kernel parameter `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue on a fresh Arch Linux install by enabling KMS (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting).

I'm on `Linux 4.7.4-1-ARCH`.

lspci gives
`VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)`

and modinfo gives

```
...
filename: /lib/modules/4.7.4-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko.gz
...
```

after turning on KMS.